# puppeteer click element if the text matches the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer

I'm trying to grab products from ebay and open them on amazon. So far, I have them being searched on amazon but I'm struggling with getting the products selected from the search results. Is there a way to select an element based on if the text matches from an array?

Any help greatly appreciated.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const URL =
  https: //www.amazon.co.uk/";

  const selectors = {
    searchBox: '#twotabsearchtextbox',
    productLinks: `//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]`,
  };

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/jmp_supplies/m.html?_trkparms=folent%3Ajmp_supplies%7Cfolenttp%3A1&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2046732.m1684');
  
  //Get product titles from ebay
  const grabTitles = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const itemTitles = document.querySelectorAll('#e1-11 > #ResultSetItems > #ListViewInner > li > .lvtitle > .vip');
    var items = []
    itemTitles.forEach((tag) => {
      items.push(tag.innerText)
    })

    return items
  })

  //Search for the products on amazon in a new tab for each product 
  for (i = 0; i < grabTitles.length; i++) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL)
    await page.type(selectors.searchBox, grabTitles[i++])
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.waitForXPath(selectors.productLinks);
    const product = await page.$x(selectors.productLinks)
    if (product == grabTitles) {
      await product.click();
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: Is `if (grabTitles.includes(product)) {}` the logic you want? In other words, is `product` in the `grabTitles` array?

Comment: Thank you , Yes thats the logic i want , however i have now added that as below , but unfortunately still isn't selecting the product from the results page.                 if (grabTitles.includes(product)){
            await product.click();
        }